# What is the equivalent of Tensorlab's Structured Data Fusion in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorly

I am trying to find symmetric, non-negative low rank tensor approximations. Right now, I am using Tensorlab's Structured Data Fusion model. I have not able to find an equivalent to this is Tensorflow or Tensorly. I would appreciate if anyone could advise me on how such a decomposition could be done in Tensorflow and Tensorly.

Comment: some links:https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_reconstruction_for_matrix_factorization
https://github.com/eesungkim/NMF-Tensorflow